# How can i theme cart page from TABLE to DIV format

Tags: theming, ubercart

I am using drupal 7 with ubercart 3.
I am not able to change the theme of CART page.
By default it is picking theming of items from tapir table.
I want to have a cart page with DIV elements and not tapir.
How to go about it ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can go into the view and change it from table to list.

Comment: there is no view created for drupal cart page.. it is created with rendering of a form called uc_cart_view_form